# Django: uses two url patterns/functions for one call

Tags: django, django-urls

I have the following urlpatterns, in this order:

```
 url(r'^([^//]*)/forum/topics/$', showThreadTopics),
 url(r'^([^//]*)/$', redirectFrontPage)
```

I go to:

```
http://localhost:8000/xxx/forum/topics/
```

showThreadTopics is called and the page is correctly shown. However, I happened to have a breakpoint set in redirectFrontPage and saw that this function is also called. This happens every time and I can print statements from it. It has no effect on the final result and does not cause any apparent network activity when looking in Firebug. There is nothing special about showThreadTopics. It just gets some data and renders them. Actually, redirectFrontPage is called with any of my urls.

How is that even possible? How do I avoid it? I have that last urlpattern because if someone types

```
www.mysite.com/users_site_name
```

then I want to redirect it to

```
www.mysite.com/users_site_name/home
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that a static reference on the page, to something like a CSS, JS or image file, is being intercepted by that URL, since it captures everything that isn't previously captured by anything else. It may even be the browser's automatic request of a favicon.